# Zkteco Tad php Library cannot connect

Tags: php, phplib

I'm Using this Php Library for Zkteco device. But it seems not working or connecting to the device [Github Link](https://github.com/cobisja/tad-php).

---

> Fatal error: Uncaught TADPHP\Exceptions\ConnectionError: Imposible iniciar conexión con dispositivo 192.168.2.63 in D:\xampp\htdocs\tad-php-master\lib\TAD.php:408 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\tad-php-master\lib\TAD.php(271): TADPHP\TAD->check_for_connection() #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\tad-php-master\test.php(20): TADPHP\TAD->__call('get_date', Array) #2 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\tad-php-master\lib\TAD.php on line 408

---

This is the current code I'm trying to do but it is getting an error.

```
<?php
require 'lib/TADFactory.php';
require 'lib/TAD.php';
require 'lib/TADResponse.php';
require 'lib/Providers/TADSoap.php';
require 'lib/Providers/TADZKLib.php';
require 'lib/Exceptions/ConnectionError.php';
require 'lib/Exceptions/FilterArgumentError.php';
require 'lib/Exceptions/UnrecognizedArgument.php';
require 'lib/Exceptions/UnrecognizedCommand.php';


$tad_factory = new TADPHP\TADFactory();


use TADPHP\TADFactory;
use TADPHP\TAD;

 $tad = (new TADFactory(['ip'=>'192.168.2.63']))->get_instance();
$dt = $tad->get_date();
// if($tad->is_alive())

// {
//  echo "Done";
// }
// else
// {

//  echo"Dead Connection";
// }
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- <input type="text" name="" value="<?php echo $firmware;?>"> -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make sure the IP is correct. That seems to be error saying.

Comment: @Justinas The IP Was correct ``Reply from 192.168.2.63: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64 `` and also i can connect using ZkAccess 3.5

Comment: @ewasketyra did you found any solution?
i'm facing the same problem!